# How to invert a dictionary?

Tags: pseudocode

I'm working with a custom language based on C with limited resources (some C-like, others added up based on other languages). I have only non-dynamic arrays and matrices, I also have dictionaries, stacks, queues and heaps, if's, for, and while cicles.

My problem is: having a dictionary with key: 'a' (int) and value: 'b'(int), and using these non-dynamic structures, how could I invert the dictionary in a simple way, that I'd have a new dictionary as following:
key: 'b'(int), value: 'a'(int[ ])

Comment: `for each dictionary element: temp <- key, key <- value, value <- temp`. Or am I missing something? You didn't say what procedural operations are available.

Comment: This is only possible if keys and values are unique. There isn't really a smart trick for this, you'll just have to re-implement a hashtable/map and alter the functions to account for bidirectional relations. Take a look at the guava implementation of a `HashBiMap`: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.java

Comment: @mbratch the problem is that in the original dictionary for the same v there may be multiple keys. In the new dictionary, the objective is that for a given key (old value) there is a set of values (old keys)

Comment: @dtech The keys are of course unique in the old dictionary, but not the values. By inverting, I should get a set of values (old keys) for each new key (old value). That's why while int the old dictionary I had a int as the value type, and in the new one, I'm using an array.

Comment: Thanks EBM. I wasn't sure what the assumption was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the non-dynamic memory as the biggest problem, and not worrying about processing time or the size of intermediate artifacts, how about:

1) Pour the original dictionary into a list of tuples in the other order. Then sort it:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

produces

```
[[1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [3, 'c']]
```

2) walk through this list, iterating over the unique first values and building a list of the mapped values (i.e. the original keys).

... produces

```
{'1': ['a', 'b'], '2':['c']}
```

3) throw away the intermediate list & reclaim that memory.

Depending on the size of things and how fast it needs to be, you could even add a step (1.5) that walks through the intermediate list and figures out all the memory requirements, then pre-allocates lists of the right size for each element. Again, that's worrying most about the lack of dynamic memory, and trying to come up with a end result that is "right sized" from the start.

Comment: Thank you, seems like a smart way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Or at least you shouldn't. Why? Because suppose you have two keys with the same value...

Otherwise, in pseudocode:

```
create dictionary BAR
for each key in dictionary FOO
    BAR[FOO[key]] = key
```

Comment: It is possible if keys and values are unique (called bidirectional map)